# Code on vscode on mac doesn't work when I include "file"

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWe2i.png)

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  DayMonth::Nhap(), referenced from:
      _main in main-8dce05.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I want run many files but when I #include "file",  it doesn't work. I've found ways to fix it on windows.
I code on vscode for mac, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Code Runner extension is for simple single-file programs. For multi-file ones you need to write `tasks.json` (either calling the compiler directly, or using some estabilished build system, like Make or CMake).

Comment: If you are going to use VSCode (and I understand that options are limited on the Mac) then you really need to read the documentation. VSCode is very complex, and you need to understand how it builds programs (or more precisely how it's extensions build code).

Comment: If you are newbie then you should learn to use Xcode on Mac first. That has its own pains but at least Mac manufacturer does not fight against its usage/usefulness for programming.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Does Apple fight against the usefulness of VSC?

Comment: @ ÖöTiib Apple   can xcode compile many files ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Obviously. Every greedy toolmaker wants to make tools of others to look bad. There are regulations so it does what it can within those limitations.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Can you elaborate what are those regulations? Do they not apply to XCode too?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes. so XCode will be kind of force-updated with updated operating system. I meant regulations by jurisdictions. Apple is well-known target of antitrust lawsuits ... so it is part of its business strategy to create various competition barriers to others.

Comment: @ÖöTiib This is all very vague. What does XCode auto-updates have to do with hindering the use of VSC?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It has been constant every-update life for years. Apple changes something in compiling, packaging, signing of apps and updates its Xcode accordingly proactively. Other development tools (and scripts of those) will fail and will update reactively after a while.

Comment: @Öö Tiib XCode does not auto-update with OS updates. It updates via the App Store, and the bigger releases are generally timed to coincide with major OS updates, but the reasoning for that should be obvious. VS Code also auto-updates. The other situation you describe is how development is in the context of major updates. I'm pretty sure newer releases of VS also break some older projects when the maintainers decide to use the new stuff. But I installed brew's LLVM and am not even beholden to that. So what, again, are these restrictions?

Comment: @sweenish but it is all so trivial. Whatever new "because Apple cannot check it for malicious software" issues every time. So developer better updates registers and distributes through Apple chains or customers have to wiggle and struggle to get it installed.

Comment: That's a completely separate issue from "Apple makes VS Code difficult to use" and isn't related. When I first installed VS Code, yes there was a pop-up, and then I told the computer to run it anyway. And that was it. You don't like Apple, whatever. Just stop making stuff up about why you don't like them, or conflating two separate issues.

Comment: @sweenish I don't like Apple? I like it. I have participated in making several successful products for its devices. I just liked it more when Steve Jobs was alive. But engineer has to see things clearly, otherwise rather expensive incorrect decisions will be made. And first decision is to learn to use Xcode on mac for reasons given. Other tools can be used as supplementary to it if you like those.

Comment: Those reasons given don't stand up with respect to C++. That's been the whole point of this conversation. That your reasoning on this matter is bad. VS Code is not held back or restricted in any way on macOS. C++ is not restricted or held back in any way on macOS. And if you afford me a little grace, it's very easy to assume to you don't like Apple. Because in *this* conversation, all you've done is put forward petty and unrelated complaints.

Comment: @sweenish I gave advice. How "petty" one or other sly and greedy garbage is ... is up to courts to decide. It does damage experience of my end users too. Apple would do better putting that effort into improving experience of users.

Comment: The argument is that it’s either unrelated or incorrect. In the context of this question. As a further example, Apple’s court case with the DOJ has nothing to do with **this question**.